# Why is the GPS tag unstably attached to photos on Android?

Tags: image, gps, exif, android-exifinterface

I developed a web-application and I need to take the exif-location on the image from the camera, but on my phone, Honor 9X, it is not always attached to the image. How can I improve the GPS linking to exif-data of photos?

I have set the following settings:

1. WiFi and Bluetooth
2. Give all roots for browser and camera
3. Enabled accurate geolocation from Google

Comment: The program must have a GPS fix, which may take time (especially indoor), but the photo need to be saved. And various programs may limit the EXIF data (for privacy).

Comment: Saved images randomly has gps-marker. I tried to load images from camera and gallery. I can't notice any pattern.